# How can I add an image (or text) to a pyqt5 QtabWidget with no tabs?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

Below is an image of a tab widget without any tabs. When tabs appear I would like the image to disappear.

[image: Empty tab - "here" shows where I would like an image]

The only code I can provide for this issue (I guess) is

`self.tab_widget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.central_widget)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there is no native method that enables this. You after you add or remove a tab from the `tab_widget` you could just swap the `tab_widget` with another widget when there are no tabs left. And swap it back once you add a tab again.
This is obviously not the move elegant solution, but it works.

Comment: So a `QStackedWidget` could be used I guess?

Comment: You `tab_widget` is part of your central layout, right?

Comment: It's part of my central widget which is of type `Qwidget`. I think I know of a solution. Place a `QstackedWidget` in my central widget then place my image and `tab_widget` in the `QstackedWidget`. Enable one at a time...